Error fetching location: TypeError: Failed to fetch in Wix
I'm getting "Error fetching location: TypeError: Failed to fetch" error when trying to fetch the location in Wix, here is the code:
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';

$w.onReady(function () {
    // Fetch the user's location details with API key
    fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json?key=MY_KEY', {
        method: 'get'
    })
    .then((httpResponse) => {
        if (httpResponse.ok) {
            return httpResponse.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
    })
    .then((json) => {
        // Set the user's countryCode as a const
        const loc = json.countryCode;

        // Log the location to the console
        console.log('User location country code:', loc);

        // Redirect based on location
        if (loc === "DE") {
            wixLocation.to("/pricing-in");
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching location:', error);
    });
});


The code worked fine when I tested locally. Tried to use the async/await but got the same issue.
